# Two windows in python, freaking me out

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

*+*+_+*+*+_+*+*+_+*+*+_+*+*+_+*+*+_+*++*

** Never mind!  ** This question is answered! it just needed this at the bottom instead of that root beezwax...

yup.  it was the bottom.  it just needed a little code cleaning :).... never mind.  thanks anyway!

```
#omit root
app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

*+*+_+*+*+_+*+*+_+*+*+_+*+*+_+*+*+_+*+*++

I've tried hard for two hours to get rid of this second window.  After I implemented the popup to ask for the folder name, I suddenly had two windows open when the program runs.  I just want one, it's really quite aggravating.    I want this program to open one window with four buttons, and have a title above them.  one of the buttons asks for input, and then it goes away.  can someone help me get back to one window?  thank you.  i apologize for the messy code, it's my first script of this style.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
            #from Tkinter import *
            import Tkinter as tk

            import os
            import tkFileDialog

            class App(tk.Tk):
            #class App:

                #def __init__(self, master):
                def __init__(self):
                tk.Tk.__init__(self)


                frame = tk.Frame(self)
                frame.pack()

                self.button = tk.Button(frame, text="leave", fg="red", command=frame.quit)
                self.button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

                self.fetch = tk.Button(frame,text="Choose Folder for Pictures",fg="salmon",command=self.choose)
                self.fetch.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

                self.fetch = tk.Button(frame,text="Name folder on site (public)",command=self.on_click)
                self.fetch.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

                self.hi_there = tk.Button(frame, text="Create code for images", fg="brown", command=self.generate)
                self.hi_there.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
                #oroville dam is the highest in the country
                w = tk.Label(text="MSP Art File Fetcher")
                w.pack()
             # Toplevel window

                top = self.top = tk.Toplevel(self)
                myLabel = tk.Label(top, text='Name of image directory:')
                myLabel.pack()

                self.myEntryBox = tk.Entry(top)
                self.myEntryBox.pack()

                mySubmitButton = tk.Button(top, text='Done', command=self.submit_name)
                mySubmitButton.pack()

                top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.save_top)

                top.withdraw()



                def save_top(self):
                self.top.withdraw()


                def choose(self):
                self.foldername=tkFileDialog.askdirectory()
                print self.foldername


                def name(self):
                print self.foldername

                def generate(self): 
                print self.foldername  
                    self.path=self.foldername  # failing, works
                self.dirlist=os.listdir(self.path)
                yoz = file('demcode.txt','wt')#totally works
                f=open('demcode.txt', 'r+')
                f.write(self.foldername)
                f.write('\ndo not be a crack addic\n')
                f.write('\n')
                print self.dirlist
                print self.dirlist[0]
                self.y=len(self.dirlist)
                print self.y
                for x in range(0,self.y): #works great
                #for x in range(0,4):#self.y: #failing
                    print 'We\'re on image %d' % (x)
                #print in self.dirlist
                f.write('\n'.join(self.dirlist[0]))#returns a vertical word!?
                f.write('\n')   
                f.write(self.dirlist[0])
                f.write('\n')
                f.write('\n')
                f.write('\n')   
                f.write(', '.join(self.dirlist))#CAUTION, will write over existing data

                def say_hi(self):
                print "don't be a crack addic"

                def submit_name(self):
                if self.myEntryBox.get() != "":
                    self.username = self.myEntryBox.get()
                    self.myEntryBox.delete(0, 'end')
                    self.top.withdraw()

                def on_click(self):
                self.top.deiconify()
            """
                def show_name(self):
                self.mainText.delete('1.0', 'end')
                self.mainText.insert('end', 'Welcome ' + self.username + '!')
            """
            root = tk.Tk()

            app = App()

            root.mainloop()
            """
            """
            achieve this format of html.  python program will loop every file in the directory, placing the name of the file in the set path (asked directory name), and write the approiate code for lightbox
            """
            <h1>MSP (Acorns) Gallery</h1>
            #http://www.mspart.com/lightbox.html
            <div id="page">
            <div id="images">
            <ul class="gallery">
              <a href="images/Pastels/alpha_farm.jpg" rel="lightbox"> </a>
              <li><a href="images/Pastels/alpha_farm.jpg" rel="lightbox"><img src="images/Pastels/alpha_farm.jpg" alt="description"></a></li>
              <a href="images/Pastels/_day_island.jpg" rel="lightbox"> </a>
              <li><a href="images/Pastels/_day_island.jpg" rel="lightbox"><img src="images/Pastels/_day_island.jpg" alt="description"></a>
            </li></ul>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: yeah, i just made my profile.  There is a strange eight hour block from overflow preventing me from adding an answer or marking it as solved...

Answer (score 0):

In your `app` class, you have already defined a `Tk`. So, when you define an `app` and another `Tk`, you are creating two windows. Removing one or the other should create only one window.